# Entity component system - where did attributes and behaviors come from?

Tags: entity-system

I recently spent quite some time understanding and building a component-based system. I got stuck on  a few problems and after searching for quite some time ran across [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/23759/2287) which is talking about behaviours and attributes.

From what I understand, attributes are an entity's data; I thought that's what the component is? And what are behaviours? Is it another term for *Entity Processing System*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Attributes and behaviors are just a different way of talking about components and systems.

- Attributes == Components
- Behaviors == Systems

They can be the exact same at the code level, it's just a different way to talk about them that might help people better understand them.

Comment: Related: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/31491/7191