# Handling game logic events by behavior components

Tags: c++, component-based, events

My question continues on topic discussed [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/23755/using-component-based-entity-system-practically)

I have tried implementing attribute/behavior design
and here is a quick example demonstrating the issue.

```
class HealthAttribute : public ActorAttribute
{
public:
    HealthAttribute( float val ) : mValue( val ) { }

    float Get( void ) const { return mValue; }
    void Set( float val ) { mValue = val; }

private:
    float mValue;

};


class HealthBehavior : public ActorBehavior
{
public:
    HealthBehavior( shared_ptr< HealthAttribute > health )
        : pHealth( health )
    {
        // Set OnDamage() to listen for game logic event "DamageEvent"
    }

    void OnDamage( IEventDataPtr pEventData )
    {
        // Check DamageEvent target entity
        // ( compare my entity ID with event's target entity ID )

        // If not my entity, do nothing
        // Else, modify health attribute with received DamageEvent data
    }

protected:
    shared_ptr< HealthAttribute > pHealth;

};
```

My question - is it possible to get rid of this annoying check for game logic events?
In the current implementation when some entity must receive damage, game logic just fires off event that contains damage value and the entity id which should receive that damage.
And all HealthBehaviors are subscribed to the DamageEvent type, which leads to any entity possesing HealthBehavior call OnDamage() even if he is not the addressee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution by myself.

It turned out that I missed the point where every entity should have own event manager.
So, I modified the code:

```
HealthBehavior( shared_ptr< HealthAttribute > health )
    : pHealth( health )
{
    // Set OnDamage() to listen for entity local event "DamageEvent"
}
```

Now, behaviors dont care about game logic, they listen only to events triggered by their own event manager.
And the game logic now fires event to entity's local event manager instead of global event manager:

```
// somewhere in game logic
{
    // simplified example of usage
    GetEntity( entityId )->GetEventManager()->TriggerEvent( damageEvent );
}
```

This way OnDamage() gets called only for target entity, so we can remove the check.